# not able to use for loop in shell script with values 01,02,03

Tags: shell

i am not able to use for loop in shell script with values 01,02,03...
i am trying with code-:

```
m=`(date +"%d-%m-%Y") | awk -F '-' '{print $2}'`
d=`(date +"%d-%m-%Y") | awk -F '-' '{print $1}'`
limit=`expr $d - 2`
for (( i=$m;i>=01;i-=1 ));
do
 for(( j=$limit;j>=01;j-=1 ));
   do
    echo -e "$j-$i-2013"
   done
done
```

my query is that the files are in format 2013-09-01,2013-08-02....but values i get from loop is 1,2,3,4 which does not match with the name of file.
i am getting error-;
actually i have to automate log files on server. i want that script will compress files till present date -2 days.
    compress_log.sh: line 6: ((: i=09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
also

Comment: Your program has a very tight race condition, where `m` may be set just prior to midnight and `d` just after. Call `date` once and save the result, then parse the value into `m` and `d`. Your `for` loops suggests you are using `bash`, so try `IFS="-" read d m Y <<< $(date +%d-%m-%Y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for loop with value 01,02,03 can be achieved by for i in 0{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} do echo $i done .... so when you use $i it will have value as required 01,02,03....
below is the script i had used-:

```
for i in 0{1,2,3,4,5}
   do
    for j in 0{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
      do
  echo -e "$i,$j\n"
      done
  done
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that numbers starting with 0 are interpreted as octal numbers and 8 and 9 are not in the base-8 number system, hence the error.

From `man bash`:

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers. A leading
>   0x or 0X denotes hexadecimal. Otherwise, numbers take the form
>   [base#]n, where base is a decimal number between 2 and 64 represent-
>   ing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base. If base# is
>   omitted, then base 10 is used.

To fix this issue, convert to base-10 by adding `10#` to the number as shown below:

```
month=10#$(date +%m)
day=10#$(date +%d)
```

Also, if you need only the month, use `date +%m`. No need for `awk`.

---

Update: If you want to left pad a number with zeros, use `printf` like this:

```
printf "%02d" $month
```

Your updated script would be:

```
m=10#$(date +%m)
d=10#$(date +%d)
limit=$(( d - 2 ))
for (( i=m;i>=1;i-- ))
do
 for(( j=limit;j>=1;j-- ))
 do
    printf "%02d-%02d\n" "$j" "$i"
 done
done
```

Comment: hi dogbane i had tried as you suggested but does not get output as per my need coming output is 9-1 ..instead i need to get 09-01...

Comment: I've updated my answer showing how you can add zero padding to the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m=`(date +"%d-%m-%Y") | awk -F '-' '{printf "%2d", $2}'`
d=`(date +"%d-%m-%Y") | awk -F '-' '{printf "%2d", $1}'
```

Getting your awk results in integer format

Also make changes in your for loop, if this is what you tried to achieve

```
for (( i=$m;i>=1;i-=1 ));
do
  for(( j=$limit;j>=1;j-=1 ));
  do
    result=`expr $j - $i`
    echo $result
  done
done
```

Comment: tried but got error-:compress_log.sh: line 7: ((: i=%2d 09: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "%2d 09")

Comment: i am really sorry but i guess you interpreted my question wrongly....actually my log files are in format 01-09-2012 so i want use loop to iterate these log files...i don't want to subtract.

Comment: for loop with value 01,02,03 can be achieved by for i in 0{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} do echo $i done .... so when you use $i it will have value as required 01,02,03....

Comment: if any anybody have any query in this regard they may post there feedbacks so that i may improve this answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
m=`(date +"%d-%m-%Y") | awk -F '-' '{printf "%02d", $2}'`
d=`(date +"%d-%m-%Y") | awk -F '-' '{printf "%02d", $1}'`
```

It has a difference where %2 will return a space and the number if the input is a single digit number, and %02 will append a 0 in this case

Comment: i am able to get 01,02 etc for m and d but when i use them in loop it changes to 1,2,3